# Lottie animations starts playing when layer that contains it is clicked, how to stop this?

Tags: reactjs, lottie

I've got a lottie animation that I trigger from a parent component, the problem is that for some reason the entire lottie component layer is clickable and initiates the animation.

This is the code code that I'm using:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isStopped: true,
      isPaused: false,
      Animated: 0,
    };
    this.defaultOptions = {
      loop: false,
      autoplay: false,
      animationData: animationData
    };
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ 
        isStopped: false,
        Animated: 0
    });
    console.log("clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="ethdrop">
        <Lottie
          className='animation-class'
          options={this.defaultOptions}
          isStopped={this.state.isStopped}
          isPaused={this.state.isPaused}
          Animated={this.state.Animated}  
        />
    </div>
    );
  }
```

This is how the dom looks like: [image: screenshot of my element inspector]

I can't find anything that might be triggering this if any of you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: What is supposed to trigger the clickHandler() ?

Comment: A button click within another component, that works just fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an undocumented property: `isClickToPauseDisabled`. When this is set to `false` (which is the default value), you can pause and resume your animation by clicking on it. If you don't want this to happen, set this property to true.

Example:

```
<Lottie options={this.defaultOptions}
    ...
    isClickToPauseDisabled={true} 
/>
```

Reference: https://github.com/chenqingspring/react-lottie/pull/54

Comment: That's nuts, solved it by having a giant transparent div over the animation. Which ofcourse is far more hacky than your soltion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do this change in your clickHandler:

```
clickHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
     this.setState({ 
        isStopped: false,
        Animated: 0
     }); 
    console.log("clicked"); 
};
```

Hope it helps.